# Acquiring Microsoft Expression Blend

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, blend

I'm having some serious trouble downloading Microsoft Expression Blend. I want to learn to work with Microsoft Silverlight, so I downloaded Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web Update 1. 
I have created a silverlight project and edited it successfully, and now I'm at the point in my learning in which Expression Blend comes in handy (animations and styling).

On the Microsoft Expression [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/), it is clearly stated that *"Blend continues to ship as a standalone tool with Visual Studio 2013".* However, I cannot find Blend anywhere on my Windows 7 laptop, nor do I see any way to open Blend from within Visual Studio.

I *do* know that all the things that can be done in Expression Blend *can* be done in Visual Studio programmatically, but I would prefer to do them visually in Blend.

To use Expression Blend, do I need a different version of Visual Studio (Web vs Desktop etc.)? Do I need to update Visual Studio? Is it required that I buy the professional edition?

Comment: Sounds to me that you are confusing the words "Express" and "Expression".  Express primarily means "download fast to get going", not very compatible with the Expression product, it is rather large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your link it states:

> You can download Blend for Visual Studio 2013 with **Visual Studio Express for Windows, Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone**, and **Visual Studio Professional 2013 and higher**.

No mention of Visual Studio for Web. So you need to Download one of the above mentioned express versions or spring for the professional edition.

Comment: Is Visual Studio Express for Windows able to create Silverlight projects?

Comment: unfortunately I have a Professional Version, so I can not specifically address what or what not can be created in Visual Studio Express. the version of blend that I got will create a WPF or an Silverlight project. You can have multiple editions installed so I would probably download it and see.  You are going to be mainly concerned wether or not Blend will handle Silverlight. Be aware that if you have updated your existing VS install you will have to update it again.